# Can we use lucene query to have fts_alfresco search?

Tags: lucene, alfresco

I want to upgrade my Alfresco server to 5.2 and in all my custom webscripts am using lucene queries. Since from Alfresco 5.x lucene indexing has been removed and solr indexing is not instantaneous, am planing to use fts_alfresco search. While testing i found that few lucene queries can be used for fts_alfresco search without modifying. So my concern is will i be able to do fts_alfresco search using lucene query? If no, is there any better way to migrate all my lucene queries to fts_alfresco?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to test/check your queries since there are small differences (for instance, date range query is not the same), but in general there's no reason why you would not be able to use FTS.

I'm not sure a comprehensive documentation exists where you would see all those small differences, though. If you find it, please share.

"Alfresco FTS is compatible with most, if not all of the examples here.."
https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4673-search